# Filter out values dynamically from a select using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a select where I am populating certain values as below:

The values are:

```
     $scope.obj = {codes: [
        {code: 1},
        {code: 2},
        {code: 3}
     ]};
```

Now I want to filter certain values dynamically without making any changes in the $scope.obj value i.e. I don't want to display the {code:1} value. I have set this value in another $scope variable:

$scope.selectedCode = {code:1};

Whatever values is present in selected code should not be displayed in the select drop down. I think this can be done using angular js filter expression:

```
<select ng-options="c.code for c in obj.codes | filter:'c.code !== selectedCode .code'" ng-model="selected">
```

But the above is displaying an empty drop down.

Any help/guidance is most welcome.Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: There is a typo in your code snippet. You have 'filer' instead of 'filter'. Is that your actual snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create helper method in controller:

```
$scope.filterCodes = function(obj) {
    return obj.code !== $scope.selectedCode.code;
};
```

and use it as custom filter:

```
<select ng-options="c.code for c in obj.codes | filter:filterCodes" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

**UPD**. There is also pure template solution without controller function:

```
ng-options="c.code for c in obj.codes | filter: '!' + selectedCode.code"
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a million. :)

Comment: In template you can do it like this: `ng-options="c.code for c in obj.codes | filter: '!' + selectedCode.code"`. But personally I find it more comprehensive to have filtering in controller and keep templates as simple as possible.

Comment: I looked everywhere for something like this !! thanks a million !!

Comment: You've just saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Tyr to create a new object which filtered.

```
<select ng-options="c.code for c in filteredobj = (obj.codes | filter:'code':'!'+ selectedCode.code)" ng-model="selected">
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer ain't working. In fact the select is not displaying any values.